# Outlook was redirected to the server clblgn.sceur.ch to get new settings

Tags: phishing, outlook

I (that is, we, our company) has clicked on "Allow" when Outlook has presented us with a redirect to `autodiscover-s.outlook.com` on our macs to get new settings. Today, we got a popup asking to connect to clblgn.sceur.ch to get new settings. I fear some security breach, can someone tell me what this might be?

Thank you.

[image: Here is a picture of the scary popups]

Comment: You was most probably staying at an hotel and using their WiFi. Maybe one of the Scandic Hotels in Europe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serving IP for that URL is 83.97.124.41.  That is an IP owned by HoistGroup SA.  They provide networking and communication services for the global hospitality industry.  I definitely wouldn't trust that link.

For this particular issue with outlook check out Microsoft's page to probe connectivity issues. testconnectivity.microsoft.com

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if this is the result of an infected Mac or something on the office 365 server?

Comment: @pusle https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/  <-- Have you tried running through this?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I did not know about that page. This will hopefully give me some answers and peace of mind. I will mark this as solved.